# sound problem with DAC on web radio

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

using RPi 2 headless with DAC audio, on NAD ampli

last week, after boot problem, format and install again Raspbian.

since i can't get sound from web radio, 
like this fipradioplayer

i get sound from youtube on web browser, but not from this web radio
i get sound from mp3 on VLC too.

any help please ?

this RPi is only for this use, with browser run at boot
with the link of the radio, for music at home.

web browser is epiphany or firefox ( for test but didn't work too)

thanks from France.

Pat

edit after pulseaudio install and pavucontrol

error to connect

edit 2 : test `pulseaudio -v`
[image: pulseaudio -v]

Answer (score 1):

You may have a problem that's unrelated to the fact that you're using a DAC, but with the radio webpage itself. This may be an easily fixable issue, however, I will offer a different approach:

After inspecting the webpage source, I noticed that the radio stream it plays is at th following URL: http://audio.scdn.arkena.com/11016/fip-midfi128.mp3. You can play this stream from VLC, mpv or whatever desktop player you like, and it should be much more stable and less resource-heavy than the web-based player.

Comment: thanks a lot, i'll try this on VLC, but what do you mean about :This may be an easily fixable issue,

Comment: Are you using PulseAudio? If so, could you please run pavucontrol and see if an audio stream appears when you open the webpage in firefox? The stream is usually called "CubebUtils". If it doesn't appear, it means that firefox doesn't even open the audio stream, and the problem is webpage-related. If it does appear, you could see if it is piped into the correct device, and if it isn't muted.

Comment: i use alsa config, don't know about pulseaudio. thanks again, i'll check that at home and reply here

Comment: Pulseaudio is an audio layer which acts above ALSA. You can read about it in the [debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/PulseAudio). I think firefox (and other browsers) require pulseaudio to play sound, or at least their non-pulseaudio library support is buggy.

Comment: is pavucontrol installed with pulseaudio ? i've just to do `apt-get install pulseaudio` to get both ? neewbie style :)

Comment: Usually not. Apparently, there's a debian package called "pavucontrol", so you'll need `apt-get install pavucontrol` :)

Comment: ok, thanks a lot again !! i'll do that at home ! that make me crazy !

Comment: pulseaudio is already installed, i do the pavucontrol install too, but i get a fatal error when i run pavucontrol i get this  pavucontrol

** (pavucontrol:932): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files

(pavucontrol:932): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_main_quit: assertion 'main_loops != NULL' failed
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.

(pavucontrol:932): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_main_quit: assertion 'main_loops != NULL' failed

Comment: and thanks for VLC use, that works !! still trying to use browser ,

Comment: Are you sure you don't get another error? GTK+ error messages are often misleading - you get words like "CRITICAL" and "assertion xxxxx failed", but they are just warnings. None of these seems to be fatal. Does the pavucontrol command exit immediately?

Comment: i get this error when i try to run pavucontrol by command line, on desktop i get error too by window "can't open " no more,

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot?

Comment: ok, i'll do later at home, i've screen shoot of command line and one by desktop, thanks for your help, since we have music by VLC :)

Comment: question edited with screenshot, thank you , for information i use x11 to manage Rpi headless, maybe something is wrong between session

Comment: Apparently, pulseaudio is not running. Can you try running "pulseaudio -v" in a terminal and post the output?

Comment: Apparently pulseaudio does start, it's just not autostarted for some reason. You can start it in background with `pulseaudio -D`. You could try changing `autostart = yes` in /etc/pulse/client.conf to persuade it to autostart.

Comment: ok, thank a lot for your help, i'll try this at home, have a nice day